# Users wanted a Calendar change from Saturday to Wednesday csv file export

Tags: java, sql, spring

I started off by replicating the issue that the users were having, used that in SQL developer to determine the query that would need to be changed. Then I found a query that would resolve the issue. Now I'm getting a syntax error, after I have applied the changed logic to the old query.

Oracle Data base, and a JPQL

Original Query

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT new UiIdDescriptionDto( "
            + " c.weekId, "
            + " c.weekDate " 
            + ") "
            + "FROM CalendarHierarchy c "
            + "WHERE c.weekId BETWEEN :weekId1 AND :weekId2 "
            + "ORDER BY c.weekId ASC "
```

New Query that retrieves proper data users wanted

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT new UiIdDescriptionDto( "
            + " c.weekId, "
            + " to_char(to_date(c.weekDate,'MM/DD/YYYY')-3,'MM/DD/YYYY') "              
            + ") "
            + "FROM CalendarHierarchy c "
            + "WHERE c.weekId BETWEEN :weekId1 AND :weekId2 "
            + "ORDER BY c.weekId ASC "
```

[UPDATE]
So now, I don't get any errors at compile time and it query's properly to csv... however, in the ide it complains that I have 2 errors, both underlining in red the to_char open and close parenthesis. Is this something I should worry about? or leave as is?

Comment: What compile error are you getting?  Please show more code than just a couple of lines, because often an error on one line shows up somewhere else.  Also, please  show your code by pasting it into the question, so that we can pick it up and try it ourselves. 
 Linking to a graphic is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I'd say that if the IDE is reporting an error, but `javac` isn't, and the database isn't, then the IDE can be safely ignored.

Comment: okay, thank you, I'm just an Intern and they have seemed to kind of just throw random things at me that I have never done before, just don't want to be like " I fixed it" and them be like wtf is this. lol